# assign file to be uploaded path to fileUpload control after postback

Tags: c#, asp.net, file-upload

i hv postback event executing after i am trying to upload a file to server to ask for conformation by the user. after postback fileupload control gets cleared and i am not able to get its value after postback.
controls viewstateEnabled property is true.
How do i assign a file path to fileupload control after postback.
I know its read only!!

please do reply...

Comment: I know its read only!! - Again you want to set the value?

Comment: then how can i save the file located on local host to server by SaveAs method

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately You can't retain/assign value in FileUpload control. This is because of due to browser security reasons.

Answer (score 0):

use stream writer or contentbytes to copy the file to server in case of postback clearing fileupload control as fileupload control is read only control.

like this:

```
   private void CreateFile()
        {
            // Create a file

            FileStream newFile = new FileStream(Session["FileName"].ToString(), FileMode.Create);

            // Write data to the file
            byte[] Buffer = (byte[])ViewState["content"];
            newFile.Write(Buffer, 0, Buffer.Length);

            // Close file

            newFile.Close();

        }
```